# taking an object from string

Tags: node.js, string, object, split

I have a string like this:

```
L 03/27/2017 - 00:19:49: rcon from "ip": command "command"
{"json":"text","here":text"}
L 03/27/2017 - 00:19:49: rcon from "ip": command "command"
```

The object can look like this(you can't know how many lines there are everytime):

```
L 03/27/2017 - 00:19:49: rcon from "ip": command "command"
{
    "matchid": "",
    "gamestate": 0,
    "plugin_version": "1",
    "paused": false,
    "gamestate_string": "none"
}
L 03/27/2017 - 00:19:49: rcon from "ip": command "command"
```

The problem is how to remove the lines between the object, not how to parse it.

Thanks.

Comment: That's called "parsing". Googling that should yield many guides.

Comment: @Carcigenicate I know how to take a string and make it an object, my problem is removing the to lines of text between the object.

Comment: Ahh, the could be made clearer in the question. Couldn't you just split the string into lines, grab the second line then parse that?

Comment: @Carcigenicate the command, ip and time is different everytime so I cant just remove it.

Comment: Is the string always 3 lines?

Comment: Sorry, I really don't know what you're after. Showing an expected output for the above data might help someone help you.

Comment: @Carcigenicate I added a better example.